# Instead of opening a message box in the browser, send the value to the text bar

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

When I open the box and select a value:

[image]

It delivers the corresponding link in a message box in the browser:

[image]

I wanted this value instead of appearing in a message box, it would appear in the text bar, what line of code do I need to modify or add for this final result change to happen?

Expected outcome:

[image]

My Script:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" name="url1" id="url1" style="width: 283px;" />
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
  <script>
  d3.csv("Lista_de_Jogos.csv", function(error, data) {
    var select = d3.select("body")
      .append("div")
      .append("select")

    select
      .on("change", function(d) {
        var value = d3.select(this).property("value");
        alert(value);
      });

    select.selectAll("option")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
        .append("option")
        .attr("value", function (d) { return d.value; })
        .text(function (d) { return d.label; });
  });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the line  `alert(value);`.
And append this code

```js
 document.querySelector('#url1').value=value
```

This should works;